# find and replace multiple strings from text file in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Below is a toy text file with sample and trait information, and a measurement.

```
Sample3_trait1  8.5
Sample6_trait2 2.2
Sample7_trait1 9.2
Sample3_trait2 1.3
Sample6_trait1 10.0
Sample7_trait2 2.1
```

I would like to replace the sample column with something more informative, like the actual name of the sample (say a persons name).  This would be relatively easy in `sed` if there were only 3 Samples, e.g.

```
sed  's/Sample3/john.D/g' file.txt
```

I could do this for each "sample". But i have 100s or thousands of sample names.

What id like to do is give `sed` a text file with two columns, the original and the replacement:

```
Sample3 john.D
Sample6 mary.D
Sample7 kelly.O
....
Sample1001 amy.P
```

And have them replaced wherever they appear throughout the file (globally), i.e., whereever Sample3 is found, replace with john.D.

Is this something that I could do with a loop in Bash? I could loop over a single column (row by row), but Im not sure what to do with matched columns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: wrt `wherever they appear` - does `Sample1` appear in the text `Sample10_trait2`? How about in `FooSample1_trait2`? If the answer to either question is no then how can we identify the delimiters for `Sample`s, e.g. does the text to be matched always occur at the start of the line and is always followed by an underscore? And no, a loop in bash is always the wrong approach for manipulating text.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` to convert the second file into a `sed` script that edits the first:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/s%\1_%\2_%/' file.2 > sed.script
sed -f sed.script file.txt
rm -f sed.script
```

No loops in the Bash code.  Note the `_` in the patterns; this is crucial to prevent `Sample3` from mapping `Sample300` to `john.D00`.

If, as you should be, you are worried about interrupts and concurrent runs of the script, then (a) use `mktemp` to generate a file name in place of `sed.script`, and (b) trap interrupts etc to make sure the script file name is removed:

```
tmp=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/sed.script.XXXXXX")
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/s%\1_%\2_%/' file.2 > $tmp
sed -f $tmp file.txt
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` is better here:

```
awk -v OFS=_ 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]} 1' names.txt FS=_ file.txt
john.D_trait1 8.5
mary.D_trait2 2.2
kelly.O_trait1 9.2
john.D_trait2 1.3
mary.D_trait1 10.0
kelly.O_trait2 2.1
```

Where `names.txt` is this:

```
Sample3 john.D
Sample6 mary.D
Sample7 kelly.O
```